# Why doesn't replace columns in the new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, sum

I have a df with nations as index and years(1990-2015) as header. I want to make a new df2 where every column is the sum of 5 year, eg: 1995-1999, 2000-2004 etc
I have done this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index[:], columns=['1995', '2000', '2005', '2010', '2015'])
df2['1995'] = df.iloc[0:4].sum(axis=1)
```

But it doesnt replace the NaN values.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post a sample of `df` and `df0` unless they are the same thing....

Comment: Yes actually they are the same thing. I change the text to make it but more clear. In my original code im using also another df, and I've copied it in the question here

Comment: You should use `np.nansum` if you want to get rid of NaNs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**

Transpose and reset index with [`df.T.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
df2 = df.T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Step 2**

Using [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), group by index in sets of 5, and then sum with [`dfGroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), passing [`np.nansum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html)

```
df2 = df2.groupby(df2.index // 5).agg(np.nansum).T
```

**Step 3**

Assign the columns inplace

```
df2.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns[::5]).year  + 5
```

---

```
df = ... # Borrowed from Bharath

df2 = df.T.reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2.groupby(df2.index // 5).sum().T
df2.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns[::5]).year  + 5

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
         1995  2000  2005  2010
Country                        
IN         72    29   100     2
EG         31    40    40    24
```

Comment: Thanks Coldspeed, it works, but I need the header with the final year, so 1990 should be 1995, 1995 should be 2000 and so on. Is there a way to do it automatically with this approach, or shoul I change it manually?

Comment: @Giuseppe Fixed. You'd need `pd.to_datetime` to do arithmetic on them (otherwise they are strings)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for sum of every 5 columns after a specific column. One way of doing it is using a for loop for concatinating data after slicing i.e if you have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['IN','EG'],'1990':[2,4],'1991':[4,5],'1992':[2,4],'1993':[2,4],'1994':[62,14],'1995':[21,4],'1996':[2,14],'1997':[2,4],'1998':[2,14],'1999':[2,4],'2000':[2,4],'2001':[2,14],'2002':[92,4],'2003':[2,4],'2004':[2,14],'2005':[2,24]})
df.set_index('Country',drop=True,inplace=True)
```

```
         1990  1991  1992  1993  1994  1995  1996  1997  1998  1999  2000  \
Country                                                                     
IN          2     4     2     2    62    21     2     2     2     2     2   
EG          4     5     4     4    14     4    14     4    14     4     4   

         2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  
Country                                
IN          2    92     2     2     2  
EG         14     4     4    14    24
```

Then

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index[:])
columns=['1990','1995', '2000', '2005']
for x in columns:
    df2 = pd.concat([df2,df[df.columns[df.columns.tolist().index(x):][0:5]].sum(axis=1)],axis=1)

df2.columns= columns
```

Output :

```
         1990  1995  2000  2005
Country                        
IN         72    29   100     2
EG         31    40    40    24
```

If you want to set different columns then ,

```
df2.columns = ['1990-1994','1995-1999','1999-2004','2005-']
```

Hope it helps

Comment: HI Bharath, thanks for your answer. It gave me a problem, maybe because columns is already defined in pandas. Anyway I managed with a less elegant, but easier to understand solution:
a = df.iloc[:,0:5].sum(axis=1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index[:], columns=['1995', '2000', '2005', '2010', '2015'])
df2['1995'] = a
for each column

Comment: @Giuseppe Doing things in a loop is not a good idea when there are vectorised approaches. Please look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- convert columns [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_datetime.html)
- [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by columns (`axis=1`) by `5A` (`years`) and aggregate `sum`
- last get years from columns by [`DatetimeIndex.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html) and remove 4

---

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%Y')
df2 = df.resample('5A',axis=1, closed='left').sum()
df2.columns = df2.columns.year - 4
print (df2)
         1990  1995  2000  2005
Country                        
IN         72    29   100     2
EG         31    40    40    24
```

If need change years, also is possible add `1`:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%Y')
df2 = df.resample('5A',axis=1, closed='left').sum()
df2.columns = df2.columns.year + 1
print (df2)
         1995  2000  2005  2010
Country                        
IN         72    29   100     2
EG         31    40    40    24
```